# Methods for a specific object (not prototyped)

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'd like to write a plugin that can be used in the following manner:

```
var img = $('#someImage').Image();
```

or perhaps:

```
var img = $.Image({id: 'someImage', src: '/...'});
```

and then be able to do image-related functions:

```
img.highlight();
img.showAlter();
```

et cetera.  However, I don't want to do:

```
$.fn.highlight = function() {}
```

since that would apply to all jQuery objects and i want my method to apply only to those objects I've called .Image() on.

is what I'm asking for possible? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to place your `Image` function on the prototype (`fn`), but then have the `Image` plugin assign the `highlight` and `showAfter` functions to that specific jQuery object on which `.Image()` is called.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.Image = function( props ) {
        this.highlight = function(){
            this.each(function() {
                $(this).css('border', "5px dashed yellow");
            });
        };
        this.showAfter = function(){};
        return this;
    };
})( jQuery );


var img = $('img').Image();

img.highlight();
```

---

**EDIT:**

To clarify, `this` in the `Image` function is a reference to the jQuery object against which `Image()` was invoked.

`this` does *not* reference the `Image` function in any way.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/saYLm/

Comment: @ekkis: My answer is entirely different from @Paul's. With mine, you're assigning `highlight` and `showAfter` directly to the jQuery object as a property, so you'll be able to do `img.highlight()`.

Comment: @ekkis: I updated my answer with more information, and fixed a typo where I missed a `)`.

Answer (score 0):

$.fn.image.highlight = function() {}

assuming you have written a plugin named image this would prototype the highlight function to that object

Comment: yes but that would make me do `img.Image.highlight()` and what I want to do is `img.highlight()`